# prepopulated fields refuse to work in a django-project that is hosted on the server DO

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, django-admin, digital-ocean

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
category = TreeManyToManyField(ProductCategory, blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name='products',
                               verbose_name='Категория')
status = models.ForeignKey(ProductStatus, default=None, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                           verbose_name='Статус')
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='Наименование товара')
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='Уникальная строка')
...
code = models.CharField(max_length=6, db_index=True, default=None, blank=True, verbose_name='Код товара',
                        help_text='Код товара должен быть 6-значным')
vendor_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, db_index=True, blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Артикул')
...
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
save_as = True
inlines = [ProductDetailInline]
fields = ['category', ('name', 'slug'), ('code', 'vendor_code'), 'memory',
          'status', ('hot_deal', 'as_new', 'recommended', 'hot_sales'), ('price', 'discount'),
          'image', 'description', 'available', 'is_active', ('created', 'updated')]
prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',), 'vendor_code': ('code',)}
...
```

*Everything works correctly and correctly on a local project, but by placing the project on the server DigitalOcean, the prepopulated_fields does not work. I'm afraid to suggest that this may be due to js files in static_prod.*

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be in the js-files located in the default directories:

1. static_prod/admin/js/**change_form.js**: (grp.jQuery) change to (django.jQuery)
2. static_prod/admin/js/**prepopulated_init.js**: (grp.jQuery) change to (django.jQuery)

Do not forget that in this case the path to the files is in my project. You may have it differently, but the problem was with these js-files.